# BackgroundImage being pushed up with KeyboardAvoidView on Android with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, imagebackground

I want to stop BackgroundImage being pushed when keyboard appears and only the TextInput components and the button should be pushed up. This works fine with the current code on iOS but does not work fine on Android. I have tried with `absolute` position of `ImageBackground` and `flex` and `height` of `ImageBackground` but nothing has worked so far. Following are the code and the screenshot on Android:

```
<ImageBackground
          source={require('../../../assets/images/backgroundImage.png')}
          style={{
            // flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            // height: '100%',
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
          }}
          resizeMode='cover'>
          <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
            enabled
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}>
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                alignItems: 'center',
                paddingHorizontal: 16,
                paddingVertical: 1,
                flexDirection: 'column',
                height: '100%',
              }}>
              <Image
                source={require('../../../assets/images/logo.png')}
                style={{ marginBottom: 50 }}
                resizeMode='contain'
              />

              <SafeAreaView
                style={{
                  height: '50%',
                  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                  width: '100%',
                }}>
                <View
                  style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                    marginBottom: 10,
                  }}>
                  <TextInput
                    ref={this.classIdRef}
                    style={{
                      width: '100%',
                      backgroundColor: '#fff',
                      height: 50,
                      borderRadius: 4,
                      marginBottom: 15,
                      paddingHorizontal: 15,
                    }}
                    placeholderTextColor='rgb(218, 218, 218)'
                    placeholder='Class ID'
                    value={roomId}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setRoomId({ roomId: text })}
                  />

                  <TextInput
                    ref={this.nicknameRef}
                    style={{
                      width: '100%',
                      backgroundColor: '#fff',
                      height: 50,
                      borderRadius: 4,
                      marginBottom: 20,
                      paddingHorizontal: 15,
                    }}
                    placeholder='Nickname'
                    placeholderTextColor='rgb(218, 218, 218)'
                    value={nickName}
                    onChangeText={(text) =>
                      this.setNickName({ nickName: text })
                    }
                  />

                  <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={this.navigateToClassroomHandler}
                    style={{
                      backgroundColor: 'rgb(251, 158, 85)',
                      width: '100%',
                      height: 50,
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      borderRadius: 4,
                    }}
                    disabled={roomId === '' || nickName === ''}>
                    <Text
                      style={{
                        fontSize: 18,
                        color: '#fff',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                      }}>
                      Attend Class
                    </Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
              </SafeAreaView>
            </View>
          </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        </ImageBackground>
```

**Update 1:**
Sorry, forgot to add the screenshots (I had already added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest file):
[image]

[image]

**And with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, it looks like following:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

just give only flex: 1 in ImageBackground rather than giving extra CSS property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add this to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Then the view doesn't get shrunk and the text inputs got pushed up.

Comment: I was using `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. But I have replaced it with your suggestion and the problem still persists. Please compare the 3 screenshots I provided above under "UPDATE 1".

Comment: Please try ScrollView instead of KeyboardAvoidingView.

Comment: I don't think the Image in the center of the screen can be adjusted with ScrollView before and after the Keyboard appears, is it?